# Programmatically create variables from data object

Tags: javascript

I'm pulling a bunch of data from a Google spreadsheet and need a way to programmatically create a variable for each cell, where the name is the cell (ie A2) and the value is the cell's contents.

It should be possible since everything I need is in there. For example `data[11].title.$t` is the cell name (A2 in this case) and   `data[11].content.$t` is the cell's contents.

I can do it all manually: `var A2 = data[11].content.$t` etc etc, but I feel like there's a better way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1dKiMlM1KXnY6zjh75CUoe3KTdKuGBlaFZXfFWYxtCmM/od6/public/basic?alt=json";
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        dataType:"jsonp",
        success:function(data) {
            var data = data.feed.entry;
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why have standalone variables when an object with keys would work just as well?

Comment: I agree with Taplar said... It's likely in the most valuable format already. Can you explain what you need the explicit variables for? Make some dictionary to store the key-value pairs and reference the "variable" by looking the dictionary's index for that cell. "What do you want to achieve" vs "What do you want to do". There is likely a simpler way

Comment: @Bryce, what format is the data in that are you expecting to be working with after this transformation is done?

Comment: An object was definitely the way to go, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a few commenters have stated, it would be better to create an object that you can reference or pass around. Whether or not this kind of data structure is the best for representing a two dimensional table will be dependent on what you're trying to do with it.

You can iterate through the entire array using a for loop or with `Array.forEach`, extract the name and value, then fill the object:

```js
const entries = data.feed.entry
const result = {}
entries.forEach(entry => {
  const value = entry.content.$t,
        name  = entry.title.$t
  result[name] = value
})

console.log(result)
```

```js
const sample = [{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1dKiMlM1KXnY6zjh75CUoe3KTdKuGBlaFZXfFWYxtCmM/od6/public/basic/R1C1"},"updated":{"$t":"2019-08-09T22:58:57.024Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"A1"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"Gauge Name"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1dKiMlM1KXnY6zjh75CUoe3KTdKuGBlaFZXfFWYxtCmM/od6/public/basic/R1C1"}]},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1dKiMlM1KXnY6zjh75CUoe3KTdKuGBlaFZXfFWYxtCmM/od6/public/basic/R1C2"},"updated":{"$t":"2019-08-09T22:58:57.024Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"B1"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"Previous value"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1dKiMlM1KXnY6zjh75CUoe3KTdKuGBlaFZXfFWYxtCmM/od6/public/basic/R1C2"}]},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1dKiMlM1KXnY6zjh75CUoe3KTdKuGBlaFZXfFWYxtCmM/od6/public/basic/R1C3"},"updated":{"$t":"2019-08-09T22:58:57.024Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"C1"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"Current Value"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1dKiMlM1KXnY6zjh75CUoe3KTdKuGBlaFZXfFWYxtCmM/od6/public/basic/R1C3"}]},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1dKiMlM1KXnY6zjh75CUoe3KTdKuGBlaFZXfFWYxtCmM/od6/public/basic/R1C4"},"updated":{"$t":"2019-08-09T22:58:57.024Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"D1"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"Low"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1dKiMlM1KXnY6zjh75CUoe3KTdKuGBlaFZXfFWYxtCmM/od6/public/basic/R1C4"}]},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1dKiMlM1KXnY6zjh75CUoe3KTdKuGBlaFZXfFWYxtCmM/od6/public/basic/R1C5"},"updated":{"$t":"2019-08-09T22:58:57.024Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"E1"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"Underperform"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1dKiMlM1KXnY6zjh75CUoe3KTdKuGBlaFZXfFWYxtCmM/od6/public/basic/R1C5"}]}]

const result = {}
sample.forEach(entry => {
  const value = entry.content.$t,
    name  = entry.title.$t
  result[name] = value
})
// two ways of getting the value
console.log(result)
```

Javascript is crazy though, so do this at your own risk, but you can technically create global variables in the browser by doing `window[name]` as opposed `result[name]` but some transpilers may complain and/or using strict mode might make the code throw reference errors and it's just generally not a good idea.

Comment: Damn, yes, this is a much more elegant solution and definitely works with what I'm trying to do. Thanks so much Khauri, and everyone else who commented!